# How to parse JSON-input

Tags: json, linux, jq

I've been reading JQ-s docs for the last two days and didn't find out how to extract values and put them together.

I've got some curl-output:

```
...
{
    "key": "Agreement",
    "doc_count": 1603,
    "level_cnt": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
            "key": "INFO",
            "doc_count": 1458
          },
          {
            "key": "ERROR",
            "doc_count": 145
          }
        ]
    }
}
...
```

The task is to take the first Key and to combine it with the next Key's and their values:

`Agreement
INFO:1458
ERROR:145`

The trouble is, when I try to parse the necessary keys, their values comes together aftewards:

`jq '.aggregations.controller_cnt.buckets[].key, .aggregations.controller_cnt.buckets[].level_cnt.buckets[].key, .aggregations.controller_cnt.buckets[].level_cnt.buckets[].doc_count`

`"Agreement"
"INFO"
"ERROR"
1469
149`

How to build this jq-query?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: You are expected to make an effort. Please show your code and state where you are having trouble. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158334) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Just map it to string.

```
jq --raw-output '.key, ( .level_cnt.buckets[] | "\(.key):\(.doc_count)" )'
```

With the following input:

```
{
    "key": "Agreement",
    "doc_count": 1603,
    "level_cnt": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
            "key": "INFO",
            "doc_count": 1458
          },
          {
            "key": "ERROR",
            "doc_count": 145
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

will output:

```
Agreement
INFO:1458
ERROR:145
```

tested at [jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/um5yii0dZn).